# How to Manual Install "Google APIs ( ARM System image )" on Computer

Tags: android, api, emulation

How to Manual Install "Google APIs ( ARM System image )" on Computer

Do I need it. How do I download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download like this:

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_apis-19_r06.zip
```

19 is the revision version, change it to what you want.

Also check all list:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml

Comment: Hello @Lazy, please after download how do I install? Thanks